# Возвращать только Map, у которой значение определенного ключа равно определенной переменной

Tags: java, потоки-данных, map, filter

Есть карта:

```
Map<String, Object> columns = new HashMap<>();
```

Она создается в стриме, и наполняется там же примерно так:

```
columns.put("description", inaccessibleError.getDescription());
columns.put("errorPriority", inaccessibleError.getPriority());
columns.put("agentId", agentId);
columns.put("systemType", agentType.getDisplayName());
columns.put("fqdn", agentFqdn);
columns.put("errorMessage", p.errorMessage);
columns.put("path", path);
columns.put("errorTime", errorDateTime);
columns.put("errorCount", errorCount);
columns.put("notShownErrorCount", errorCount <= limitByPath ? 0 : errorCount - limitByPath);
columns.put("foldersTotalErrorCount", foldersTotalErrorCount[0]);
columns.put("filesTotalErrorCount", filesTotalErrorCount[0]);
return columns;
```

Собственно вопрос: мне надо возвращать только ту map, у которой ключ "errorPriority" равен заранее заданной переменной. inaccessibleError.getPriority() - стринг. Как это лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно

```
package test;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

  private final HashMap<String, Service> modes = new HashMap<>();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Map> listOfMap = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

      Map<String, Object> columns = new HashMap();

      columns.put("description", "inaccessibleError.getDescription()");
      columns.put("errorPriority", i % 2 == 0 ? "inaccessibleError.getPriority()" : "other");
      columns.put("agentId", i);
      columns.put("systemType", "agentType.getDisplayName()");
      columns.put("fqdn", "agentFqdn");
      columns.put("errorMessage", "p.errorMessage");
      columns.put("path", "path");
      columns.put("errorTime", "errorDateTime");
      columns.put("errorCount", "errorCount");
      columns.put("notShownErrorCount", "errorCount <= limitByPath ? 0 : errorCount - limitByPath");
      columns.put("foldersTotalErrorCount", "foldersTotalErrorCount[0]");
      columns.put("filesTotalErrorCount", "filesTotalErrorCount[0]");

      listOfMap.add(columns);
    }

    List result =
        listOfMap.stream()
            .filter(map -> map.get("errorPriority").equals("inaccessibleError.getPriority()"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    result.forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

и ответ

```
{path=path, errorTime=errorDateTime, foldersTotalErrorCount=foldersTotalErrorCount[0], agentId=0, errorPriority=inaccessibleError.getPriority(), fqdn=agentFqdn, notShownErrorCount=errorCount <= limitByPath ? 0 : errorCount - limitByPath, filesTotalErrorCount=filesTotalErrorCount[0], systemType=agentType.getDisplayName(), errorMessage=p.errorMessage, description=inaccessibleError.getDescription(), errorCount=errorCount}
{path=path, errorTime=errorDateTime, foldersTotalErrorCount=foldersTotalErrorCount[0], agentId=2, errorPriority=inaccessibleError.getPriority(), fqdn=agentFqdn, notShownErrorCount=errorCount <= limitByPath ? 0 : errorCount - limitByPath, filesTotalErrorCount=filesTotalErrorCount[0], systemType=agentType.getDisplayName(), errorMessage=p.errorMessage, description=inaccessibleError.getDescription(), errorCount=errorCount}
{path=path, errorTime=errorDateTime, foldersTotalErrorCount=foldersTotalErrorCount[0], agentId=4, errorPriority=inaccessibleError.getPriority(), fqdn=agentFqdn, notShownErrorCount=errorCount <= limitByPath ? 0 : errorCount - limitByPath, filesTotalErrorCount=filesTotalErrorCount[0], systemType=agentType.getDisplayName(), errorMessage=p.errorMessage, description=inaccessibleError.getDescription(), errorCount=errorCount}
{path=path, errorTime=errorDateTime, foldersTotalErrorCount=foldersTotalErrorCount[0], agentId=6, errorPriority=inaccessibleError.getPriority(), fqdn=agentFqdn, notShownErrorCount=errorCount <= limitByPath ? 0 : errorCount - limitByPath, filesTotalErrorCount=filesTotalErrorCount[0], systemType=agentType.getDisplayName(), errorMessage=p.errorMessage, description=inaccessibleError.getDescription(), errorCount=errorCount}
{path=path, errorTime=errorDateTime, foldersTotalErrorCount=foldersTotalErrorCount[0], agentId=8, errorPriority=inaccessibleError.getPriority(), fqdn=agentFqdn, notShownErrorCount=errorCount <= limitByPath ? 0 : errorCount - limitByPath, filesTotalErrorCount=filesTotalErrorCount[0], systemType=agentType.getDisplayName(), errorMessage=p.errorMessage, description=inaccessibleError.getDescription(), errorCount=errorCount}
```

Естественно в вашем случае
фильтер будет таким

```
.filter(map -> map.get("errorPriority").equals(inaccessibleError.getPriority()))
```

Comment: Дружище, я сидел с этим больше 3 часов. Глаза замылились. Спасибо тебе просто огромное!)) От всего сердца)